Is this a bug in Java data binding? I can't put my class in a custom package
When I put the classes in the default package everything's fine, Gradle gives the correct import statement.
enter image description here
When I try to put my classes in a custom package like this, Gradle gives a false import statement, it tries to import a package without '.*', like this
enter image description here
I tried to import my classes in the data node but ended up in vain
<import type="com.example.javalearningexamples.DataBindingTest.Person"/>
<import type="com.example.javalearningexamples.DataBindingTest.MyClick"/>

I want to know how I can put my classes in a default package or it's not suggested at all?

The term default package has a specific meaning in Java, namely the nameless package, and the first screenshot shows it's in a normal named package, not the default package. Have you tried using an all lowercase package name (though technically it shouldn't matter, the convention is to only use PascalCase for class names, not for package names. As an aside, it isn't Gradle adding the import, it's your IDE (I guess Android Studio).

Ah you are right....the gradle successfully recognize the package and import the class correctly, thanks a lot!

The package name has to start with a lowercase for the gradle to import the class correctly

It's not Gradle that does the import. It seems to me to be a bug in your IDE. Though the warning on top seems to indicate you're doing something wrong by putting and editing source files in the build directory, which is for build output.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
